# Drawing with GLKit

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios5, glkit

I am trying to write a game using opengl, but I am having a lot of trouble with the new glkit classes and the default template from iOS.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!self.context) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }

    if(!renderer)
        renderer = [RenderManager sharedManager];
    tiles = [[TileSet alloc]init];

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = self.context;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

    [self setupGL];
}

- (void)setupGL
{
    int width = [[self view] bounds].size.width;
    int height = [[self view] bounds].size.height;

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
    self.effect.light0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
    self.effect.light0.diffuseColor = GLKVector4Make(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f);

    //Configure Buffers
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffers(2, &colourRenderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colourRenderBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8_OES, width, height);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colourRenderBuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffers(3, &depthRenderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBuffer);

    //Confirm everything happened awesomely
    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) ;
    if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status);
    }

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Enable the OpenGL states we are going to be using when rendering
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f);


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);


    float iva[] = {
        0.0,0.0,0.0,
        0.0,1.0,0.0,
        1.0,1.0,0.0,
        1.0,0.0,0.0,
    };

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(float) * 3, iva);

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 4);

}
@end
```

With this the buffer clears(to a grey colour), but nothing from the vertex array renders. I have no idea what to do from here and due to the age of the technology there is not much information available on how to properly use glkit.

Answer (score 12):

I don't see anything in your setup code that loads your shaders - I presume you are doing this somewhere in your code?

In addition, in your setup code, you are creating your framebuffer. The `GLKView` does this for you - indeed you are telling the view to use a 24-bit depthbuffer in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
view.context = self.context;
view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;
```

So what your `glkView:drawInRect:` code above is doing is saying: "Bind my handmade framebuffer, and draw some stuff into it". The `GLKView` then automatically presents itself, but nothing has been drawn into it, you've only drawn into your handmade buffer. Unless you need additional framebuffer objects for tasks such as rendering to texture, then you don't need to concern yourself with framebuffer creation at all - let the `GLKView` do it automatically.

What you should be doing in your `setupGL` method (or anywhere you like in the setup) is creating your vertex array object(s) that remember the openGL state required to perform a draw. Then, in the `glkView:drawInRect:` method you should:

1. Clear using `glClear()`.
2. Enable your program.
3. Bind the vertex array object (or, if you didn't use a VAO, enable
   the appropriate vertex attrib pointers).
4. Draw your data using `glDrawArrays()` or `glDrawElements()`.

The `GLKView` automatically sets its context as current, and binds its framebuffer object before each draw cycle.

Perhaps try to think of `GLKView` more like a regular `UIView`. It handles most of the openGL code behind the scenes for you, leaving you to simply tell it what it needs to draw. It has its `drawRect:` code just like a regular `UIView` - with a regular `UIView` in `drawRect:` you just tell it what it should draw, for example using Core Graphics functions - you don't then tell it to present itself.

The `GLKViewController` is then best thought of as handling the mechanics of the rendering loop behind the scenes. You don't need to implement the timers, or even worry about pausing the animation on your application entering the background. You just need to override the `update` *or* `glkViewControllerUpdate:` method (depending on whether you're subclassing or delegating) to update the state of the openGL objects or view matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I made a post about the way to set up a basic project template using GLKit. You can find it here:

[Steve Zissou's Programming Blog](http://stevezissouprogramming.blogspot.ca)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the GLKit yet, but it seems that you do not present your framebuffer after drawing into it.
In an application using OpenGL ES 2 under iOs but without GLKit, I use to call the following code at the end of the rendering loop.

```
if(context) {
  [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
  [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

}

As I said I haven't used GLKit yet so I hope this might be useful.

Comment: I have seen and tried this before, but xcode refuses to compile. with the message.

    'EAGLContext' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'presentRenderbuffer:'

Comment: Importing QuartzCore fixed my build issue, but I am still not managing to draw anything.

Comment: In GLKit, the GLKView will automatically present itself and discard unneeded renderbuffers at the end of each rendering cycle. This is not the problem with the code. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to call

```
[self.effect prepareToDraw];
```

just before

```
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

As GLKit mimics the OpenGL ES 1.1 rendering pipeline, you do not need to include the routines to define Shader. GLKit actually does this for you, if you wish to use basic pipeline like OpenGL ES1.1

Comment: This is incorrect. You still need to provide shaders if working with OpenGL ES 2.0 (used for the default OpenGL ES template) and a GLKView.  Some default effects are available, but you have to set them up in GLKit using GLKBaseEffect and the like.  None of that is present in the above code.

Comment: Yes you are right in some sense, we'll setup these parameters using GLKit's GLKBaseEffect. My point here is that "You do not have to involve yourself writing the shaders explicitly if you wish to use basic pipeline.