# How can I take a programmatic screenshot of an Open GL ES 2.0 scene using GLKit (in iOS 6)?

Tags: ios6, opengl-es-2.0, screenshot, glkit

I've found numerous posts regarding this, but I haven't been able to work out a solution, largely due to the fact that I don't have a very thorough understanding of OpenGL or GLKit.

I added the method described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html) to my project.

They specifically mention:

> Important: You must call glReadPixels before calling
>   EAGLContext/-presentRenderbuffer: to get defined results unless you're
>   using a retained back buffer.

I tried unsuccessfully to [set up a retained back buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395743/glkview-set-drawable-properties) and given that doing so has 'adverse performance implications' I would rather avoid it.

The problem is, according to a comment in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807060/drawing-with-glkit):

> In GLKit, the GLKView will automatically present itself and discard unneeded renderbuffers at the end of each rendering cycle.

That being the case, **how can I call the 'Snapshot' method at the appropriate time when using GLKit?**

To date, in iOS 5 I get a weirdly yellow coloured version of the scene (as though there were no other colours) and in iOS 6 I get a pure white image (I imagine because I am using white as the clear colour).

Further, I have no idea what they (apple) are talking about in this comment:

> // If your application only creates a single color renderbuffer which is already bound at this point,
>   // this call is redundant, but it is needed if you're dealing with multiple renderbuffers.
>   // Note, replace "_colorRenderbuffer" with the actual name of the renderbuffer object defined in your class.
>   glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, _colorRenderbuffer);

so I have commented out the call in my app.  If it matters my objects are using VBOs with position, texture coords and colour.